# Im just trying to add a wait on each page

Tags: java

Hi I just want to add a wait on each of these links but struggling

Heres my code:

```
  driver.findElement(By.className("dmUDNavigationItem_03")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.className("dmUDNavigationItem_00")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.className("dmUDNavigationItem_02")).click();
```

I just need a wait for 5 seconds on each of these

Any ideas?

Comment: wait between each line ?

Comment: Struggling with what, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `Thread.sleep(5*1000);` between each of your lines, I put everything in a `foreach loop` it would be easier if you have more to add later :

```
for(String dmU : Arrays.asList("dmUDNavigationItem_03","dmUDNavigationItem_00","dmUDNavigationItem_02")){
    driver.findElement(By.className(dmU)).click();
    try{
        Thread.sleep(5*1000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ie){
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry this worked!!!!

Comment: @Warby great, so you may think about vote up / accept the answer ;)